# Removing duplicates of certain field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table looking as follows:

```
Field     | Type         | Null    | Key    | Default | Extra
----------+--------------+---------+--------+---------+----------------
index     | int(11)      | NO      | PRI    | NULL    | auto_increment
itemid    | int(11)      | NO      |        | NULL    |
name      | varchar(32)  | NO      |        | NULL    |
meta      | int(11)      | NO      |        | NULL    |
```

Table is small and  I don't have to care about optimalisation.

Some of records have `itemid`, `name`, and `meta` duplicated but I want to remove all of those that have **`name`** duplicated, leaving one record (that is no longer duplicated.) This is MySQL. I searched for the solution but I found nothing that I cound make suit my needs.

Comment: index is a reserved word. It would be better to rename it, so you will not be forced to use backticks everytime you call it.

Comment: @nick rulez: and to rewrite the code that uses this table? ;-)

Comment: Hi. alter table tbl_name change `index` id int not null auto_increment;

Comment: @nick rulez: for what reason? PK already implies the field is `not null`

Comment: You're right. It seems that alter table tbl_name change index id int auto_increment is enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data is small it could be simpler to create a table with similar structure and perform such query:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (index, itemid, name, meta)
SELECT index, itemid, name, meta FROM old_table GROUP BY name
```

After that delete `old_table` and rename `new_table`.

Also the solution that could work (I'm not sure) would be to create an unique index with `IGNORE`, like

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblname
ADD UNIQUE INDEX ix_name (name)
```

> IGNORE is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how ALTER TABLE works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If IGNORE is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If IGNORE is specified, only the first row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key, The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, to be exact:
`CREATE TABLE itemstemp AS SELECT * FROM items GROUP BY name`

Comment: @Sebi: yup, handy solution. But also try to add unique index, it would help with less steps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its what you are looking for but you could try the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT index, itemid, name, meta FROM table GROUP BY name
```